# Itunes search podcast JSON API repository sometimes does not return "feedUrl"

Tags: json, podcast

I am developping a podcast app on android and I am using the apple Itune search podcast JSON API at : https://itunes.apple.com/search

For most podcasts it works fine. I used the returned "feedUrl" to retrieve the podcast RSS.

But some JSON answers do not containt the "feedUrl" field like this one (a public french radio) :

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=podcast&term=geopolitique

{"wrapperType":"track",
"kind":"podcast",
"artistId":140064169,
"collectionId":115156820,
"trackId":115156820,
"artistName":"France Inter",
"collectionName":"Géopolitique",
"trackName":"Géopolitique",
"collectionCensoredName":"Géopolitique",
"trackCensoredName":"Géopolitique",
"artistViewUrl":"https:\/\/podcasts.apple.com\/us\/artist\/france-inter\/140064169?uo=4",
"collectionViewUrl":"https:\/\/podcasts.apple.com\/us\/podcast\/g%C3%A9opolitique\/id115156820?uo=4",
"trackViewUrl":"https:\/\/podcasts.apple.com\/us\/podcast\/g%C3%A9opolitique\/id115156820?uo=4",
"artworkUrl30":"https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Podcasts114\/v4\/00\/72\/37\/00723706-38f3-e6b4-e1f4-8f7c6d1c0c8e\/mza_10556417590921648893.jpg\/30x30bb.jpg",
"artworkUrl60":"https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Podcasts114\/v4\/00\/72\/37\/00723706-38f3-e6b4-e1f4-8f7c6d1c0c8e\/mza_10556417590921648893.jpg\/60x60bb.jpg",
"artworkUrl100":"https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Podcasts114\/v4\/00\/72\/37\/00723706-38f3-e6b4-e1f4-8f7c6d1c0c8e\/mza_10556417590921648893.jpg\/100x100bb.jpg",
"collectionPrice":0,
"trackPrice":0,
"trackRentalPrice":0,
"collectionHdPrice":0,
"trackHdPrice":0,
"trackHdRentalPrice":0,
"releaseDate":"2021-01-22T07:20:00Z"
,"collectionExplicitness":"cleaned",
"trackExplicitness":"cleaned",
"trackCount":66,"country":"USA",
"currency":"USD","primaryGenreName":"News",
"contentAdvisoryRating":"Clean",
"artworkUrl600":"https:\/\/is5-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Podcasts114\/v4\/00\/72\/37\/00723706-38f3-e6b4-e1f4-8f7c6d1c0c8e\/mza_10556417590921648893.jpg\/600x600bb.jpg",
"genreIds":["1489","26"],
"genres":["News","Podcasts"]}
```

This example do contain a *collectionId* and a *collectionViewUrl* that lead to the podcast webpage but this is not the podcast RSS feed (to parse)

I understand that the podcast owner may not have provided the "feedUrl" field to apple.

I have 2 questions :

1. Is there a workaround in this case for Apple podcast repository ?
2. Do you know other international podcast repositories (JSON API) ? I tried google or spotify ones, but I am enable to find their JSON API.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Podcasts Connect now offers podcasters the ability to hide their RSS feed from the catalog API. If you don't see the *feedUrl* field then the podcaster has unchecked the option in the Availability tab in Apple Podcasts Connect.